# Jenkins - How to concatenate ${WORKSPACE} with a string literal?

Tags: string, jenkins, groovy, coding-style

In the below scripted pipeline code(groovy syntax):

```
ws('/app/jenkins/workspace/abc/def/ghi'){
            sh './mvnw clean install
}

ws('/app/jenkins/workspace/abc/def/xyz'){
            sh './mvnw clean install
}
```

where

`/app/jenkins/workspace/abc/def`
is `${WORKSPACE}`

`ghi` & `xyz` are sub-folders within `${WORKSPACE}`

---

How to concatenate `${WORKSPACE}` with sub-folder `ghi` and store the value in `someVar`? to use the syntax `ws(someVar){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try
   ws("${WORKSPACE}/ghi"){ .... }

Pay attention to use gstring substitution must be double quotes, single quote is a typical string

Comment: Can you provide reference to gstring substitution?

Comment: GString is a first citizen in Groovy. You can read briefly about it in the javadoc http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html

basically is a string who inspect the content and perform substitution :

def a = 1
assert "a is $a" == "a is 1"

def a = 'hello'
assert "a is ${a}" == "a is hello"

Comment: What does it mean not working? Do you have any error?